# Text morph animation in React / Next Js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, css-animations

[enter link description here](https://www.animate-code.com)
I want to recreate this type of animation.
how can i implement this?

this is what i got to know until now that each letter is in a span. and then its animated to its new position.

```
'use client'


import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import DiffMatchPatch, { DIFF_INSERT, Diff } from 'diff-match-patch';

const Page = () => {
  const [frame, setFrame] = useState(0);
  const [difference, setDifference] = useState<Diff[]>([]);
  const dmp = new DiffMatchPatch();

  const getDiff = (text1: string, text2: string) => {
    const diffs = dmp.diff_main(text1, text2);
    dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(diffs);
    return diffs;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const diff = getDiff(frames[frame], frames[frame + 1]);
    setDifference(diff);
  }, [frame]);

  const frames = [
    'const isExample = animations.some(() => {})',
    `const isExample = animations.some((animation) => {
      return animation.looksAwesome()
    })`,
    'const isExample = animations.some((animation) => {\n  return animation.looksAwesome()\n})',
  ];

  const nextFrame = () => {
    setFrame(frame === frames.length - 1 ? 0 : frame + 1);
  };

  const calculateChangePosition = (changeIndex: number) => {
    const change = difference[changeIndex];
    let x = 0;
    let y = changeIndex * 20; // Adjust according to your layout
    if (change[0] === DIFF_INSERT) {
      // For insertions, set x position based on previous change's length
      x = difference
        .slice(0, changeIndex)
        .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + (curr[0] === DIFF_INSERT ? curr[1].length : 0), 0) * 10; // Adjust according to your layout
    }
    return { left: x, top: y };
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
      <div className="frame overflow-hidden transition-height duration-500 ease-in-out">
        <h1>
          <span>{"Hello"}&nbsp;</span>
          <span>{"Hello"}</span>
        </h1>
      </div>

      <div className="max-w-2xl bg-slate-600 whitespace-pre-wrap">
        <h1 className="text-md">
          {difference.map((change, index) => (
            <span
              key={index}
              style={calculateChangePosition(index)}
              className={change[0] === DIFF_INSERT ? 'insertion' : 'deletion'}
            >
              {change[1]}
            </span>
          ))}
        </h1>
      </div>

      <div>{JSON.stringify(difference)}</div>

      <div className="bg-slate-500 whitespace-pre-wrap">{frames[frame]}</div>
      <button
        className="mt-4 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onClick={nextFrame}
      >
        Next Frame
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Consider each frame has text, so i want this morphing animation type of thing for my app.
how can i do that?
how can i implement this using Framer motion or any other library.